# Building latest Vala releases (make check fails and valac can't find shared lib)

Tags: c, gcc, build, autotools, vala

I have downloaded the last two [latest releases of VALA](https://live.gnome.org/Vala/Release) (**v0.17.0** and **0.16.0**) and have attempted to build on my dev machine (Ubuntu 10.0.4 with gcc 4.4.3).

When I built v **0.17.0**, I noticed that some errors flashed across the screen. I run `make check` and `make test` and both failed (cc error).

With v **0.17.0**, when I run valac I got the following error:

> valac: error while loading shared libraries: libvala-0.18.so.0: cannot
>   open shared object file: No such file or directory

Notice the different version number for the shared lib (is this a bug?). In any case I searched my entire system to see if the file had been created some where else on my system. The file was not found.

I then downloaded v **0.16.0** and built it. `make check` and `make test` also failed again. However this time when I launched the valac executable, I got this error:

> valac: error while loading shared libraries: libvala-0.16.so.0: cannot
>   open shared object file: No such file or directory

Notice that the shlib low has the correct version number. I was hopeful, I then searched my machine for the shlib:

```
someone@yourbox:~/work/dev/c++/3rdparty/vala/vala-0.16.0$ find . -name 'libvala*' -type f 2>/dev/null
./codegen/libvala-0.16.la
./codegen/.libs/libvala-0.16.lai
./codegen/.libs/libvala-0.16.so.0.0.0
./libvala.pc
./libvala.pc.in
./vapi/libvala-0.16.vapi
./ccode/libvalaccode.la
./ccode/.libs/libvalaccode.a
./libvala-0.16.pc
./vala/.libs/libvalacore.a
./vala/libvalacore.la
```

I was about to create a symlink to the shared library, and place it in the path so that valac could find it - until I realized that I shouldn't have to be doing that (make install should already have done that).

Which leads me to believe that both v **0.17.0** and **0.16.0** are broken - is anyone else aware of this - or am I missing something?

Has anyone managed to get any of the latest releases to build - and what do I need to fix the build? (failing that, what is the last know stable release for vala)?

**[[Update]]**

I have made the build log for 0.17.0 is available [here](http://pastebin.com/nBrEwAX4)

The output from make check (again foe v 0.17.0) is also available [here](http://pastebin.com/s2xxEpDD)

Comment: I'm not aware of anyone having a similar problem, and there is no way to tell what went wrong from what you posted.  Please post a complete build log.

Comment: @nemequ: I have uploaded the build log and out pur from running `make check` to patebin. Please see my updated question for the links. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`make check` failing is unrelated.  Some of the test cases depend on the GDBus, which was only added to GIO with version 2.26, and according to http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/libglib2.0-0 Ubuntu 10.04 has 2.24.

The 0.18 you see is the API/ABI version, and is correct.  Odd numbered minor releases are unstable and carry the API/ABI version of the next stable release (think of 0.17.x releases as unstable development versions of what will eventually become the 0.18 stable series).

As for not being able to find the library, depending on the prefix you installed to you likely just need to run `ldconfig`.  AFAIK this step is no longer necessary (someone who runs Ubuntu would have to confirm that), but 10.04 was a long time ago...

If you didn't install to a standard location, you may need to adjust your LD_LIBRARY_PATH accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

ref to:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Vala

If you go with the sudo make install stuff, you could receive the following error message when you issue the first valac commmands

valac: error while loading shared libraries: libvala.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

This means that the compiler could not find the libraries, however they are exactly where they are supposed to be, namely in the directory /usr/local/lib. To correct the error at compiling time, you will run the command sudo ldconfig to update the linkers to dynamic libraries.

so you can run this command:

> sudo ldconfig /usr/local/lib

to add this library path

Answer (score 0):

I got error to:

> error while loading shared libraries: libvala-0.18.so.0: cannot open
> shared object file: No such file or directory

**SO**
I did this and now is working

`sudo apt-get install build-essential flex bison libglib2.0-dev`

`sudo apt-get install checkinstall devhelp libgtk2.0-dev`

and that set, everything is fine now.